# Laravel Request::is() - is there a better way?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-request

```php
@if(Request::is('login') OR Request::is('tags') OR Request::is('categories') OR Request::is('posts') OR Request::is('tags/..') OR Request::is('categories/..') OR Request::is('posts/..') OR Request::is("posts/{$post->id}"))
    @include('partials._navAdmin')
@else  
    @include('partials._nav')
@endif
```

Above is an example in my `main.blade.php` file; I am trying to use 2 different navigation bars - I know there is a better way to do this but I still can't get the grasp of it!

I don't think it is good coding standards to repeat `Request::is` over and over again. I am a newbie :( what did I miss over there?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[`is()`](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L182) method iterates over arguments:

```
foreach (func_get_args() as $pattern) {
    if (Str::is($pattern, $this->decodedPath())) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, something like this should work for you:

```
@if(Request::is('login', 'tags', 'categories', 'posts', 'tags/..', 'categories/..', 'posts/..', 'posts/{$post->id}'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Indeed this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For 
User Add :- 
Request::is('user/add');

User Edit :-
Request::is('user/*/edit');
Request::is('user/edit/*');